# How do you find an function equivalent to a summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Without intuitively knowing that $\left[1+2+\cdots+n\right]$ is equivalent to $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$, how would I find a function that represents $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i$ ?

If possible, I would like to know a general way to find these solutions.

Comment: If your problem is as dizzyingly broad as "find a closed form for any sum", then I'm afraid you're probably going to leave disappointed as far as a general method goes. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general answer. For example, no closed form is known for $$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}^3.$$

There is a large body of specific technique, and there is a fascinating theory that solves many such problems that you can read about in the book *A=B* by Petkovsek et al., which is [available online for free](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html).

When the summand is a polynomial, as in your example, there *is* a solution; you should look into [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). This was discovered independently by Johann Bernoulli and Seki Kōwa, both around 1700.

The book [*Concrete Mathematics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics) by Graham et al. is not too hard, and a large portion of it is devoted to techniques for evaluating summations.  For example, it  presents seven or eight different ways to obtain a closed form for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$, because this example is not too hard and illustrates the various techniques.