# How to write a sum as a function

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you go from a sum written in sigma notation to a closed-form function, in the case where it is possible to do so?  For example, what steps were taken to turn the sum  $\sum_{n=1}^k n$ into the function $S(k) = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very broad question, which is probably impossible to answer in general.

Comment: I think you mean a *closed form*. This isn't always possible.

Comment: Note that your example is not an infinite sum.

Comment: @Ethan: When I came out of high school, I thought all of mathematics was just learning procedures to do things with equations.  I found out ( to my pleasant surprise ) that this is not the case.  The question you are asking has no answer in the form of "follow these steps".  There are some results on classifying sums that have expressions in closed form with simple equations, like the one you give, but there is no magic algorithm that solves them all.

Comment: Note that I voted to close not as “too broad” but  because this question is an exact duplicate of the recent question [How do you find an function equivalent to a summation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739146/how-do-you-find-an-function-equivalent-to-a-summation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of $\sum_{n=1}^k n$, there are a number of techniques you might use.  The usual technique is to see (either by inspiration, or because someone pointed it out) that if you take the first $k$ integers in sequence and then make pairs of integers by counting an equal number of places from each end of the list, you get a list of pairs like $(1, k)$, $(2, k - 1)$, $(3, k - 2)$, and so forth.  If $k$ is even then every number in the list belongs to one of these pairs, the sum of numbers in each pair is $k + 1$ and the number of pairs is $k/2$, therefore your answer is to multiply $k + 1$ by $k/2$, and there is your formula. If $k$ is odd, then the number of pairs is only $(k - 1)/2$, but there is also the number $(k + 1)/2$ which is not part of a pair, so again you multiply the total in each pair by the number of pairs, but this time add the extra term, and again you get the same formula in terms of $k$.

More generally, if instead of $n$ you are taking a summation of some polynomial in $n$, the sum will be a polynomial in $n$ of degree one higher (so in this example, $n$ is a first-degree polynomial in $n$, and the answer is a second-degree polynomial in $n$). The trick is to figure out the coefficients of the polynomial.

I should point out, I am answering only the question of how someone might guess such a formula in the first place. Once you think you have a formula, in order to *prove* that it is the correct formula you would use a rigorous proof technique, which is usually very different from the technique by which you would first come to write a formula.  Mathematical induction is very often a good proof technique.

There are also of course many sums that are not sums of polynomials in the summation variable, and various techniques for solving the ones that people have figured out how to solve.  It really depends on what it is that you're summing.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, the easiest proof is by induction:

1. The property is true for $k=1$
2. Assume the property is true for some $k$, and prove that it must then be true for $k+1$

There is a nice way of picturing it graphically: think of a $k$-by-$k$ square with $k^2$ cells. How many cells are there under the diagonal? Well, one way of figuring this out is to count up column-by-column how many cells lie under the diagonal:
$$
0 + 1 + 2 + \dotso + (k-1)
$$
Another way of counting is to realize that you simply need to count the entire number of cells ($k^2$), remove the diagonal cells ($k$), then divide by two:
$$
\frac{k^2 - k}{2} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}
$$
and you are done.

As Alex Becker said, there is no general answer.
However, there are similar formulas for sums of higher powers, for example:

$$
1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \dotsc = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$

These are known as Faulhaber polynomials:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: I understand how to prove it, but I don't understand how, or rather the steps taken, to go from the equation in sigma notation to the equation in closed form.  Thanks!